# How to read a blob being sent through ajax to a Java server

Tags: java, httprequest, blob

So I am trying to send a BLOB image to a Java server through AJAX and then convert that to a btye array. I am able to get the BufferedInputStream; however, when I try to convert that to a byte array, the program hangs and will not continue. Does anyone know why this might be?

The client side looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/com/uploadImage/",

        data: blobImage,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
```

Here is my java code:

```
  public void handleRequest() {
    try {
       BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(this.getSocket().getInputStream());

       //this is the line that causes the program to hang
       byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(bis);
       FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("image.png"), bytes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your Java code?  Is there any sort of error output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen surprisingly, there were no errors at all. I tried debugging and I am able to read the BufferedInputStream and see the data; however, once I try to jump over the `byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(bis);` line, it just seems to get stuck;

Comment: How large is the BLOB image?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've tried it with images as small as 50kb up to a few hundred kb with the same result

Comment: My guess is that Java has nothing to do with this.  Verify that you can connect to that URL from your browser, and then verify that you can connect from Java.  My guess is that you _can't_ connect from Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is happening here, but I might be wrong. The `IOUtils.toByteArray` line is likely not going to halt until it reaches the end of the stream. Because more data could arrive over the network at any time, the call will be stuck waiting there until it knows that nothing else will arrive. It will only know this when the AJAX call on the client finishes. This suggests that the issue is that the client is stuck and therefore holding up the server.

But why is the client stuck? Because it is waiting for a response. HTTP is a two way street and the server is supposed to acknowledge the request as it comes over the socket without waiting for the connection to end.

In effect, what you should be doing instead of reading the entire thing into a `byte[]` is that you should be reading it bit by bit inside a loop. You should then respond as soon as the client has sent all the data which constitutes a request. In HTTP, the client is done requesting when it sends a blank line to the server.

This is pure speculation though, and should be treated as such. I might be missing something here.

Also, a side note - `IOUtils.toByteArray` doesn't require you to wrap your input stream in a `BufferedInputStream`.